# To change bg through extendscript, import an image into "Background composition" of after effects project

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I wants to change image from bg composition through extendscript. Reason behind this, is to reduce time to every time to go into pre-comp(BG) and manually change image.

I have tried to modify "Smart Import.jsx"(provided with AE), but this script is specially for image sequences. And modified script is not working me

```
function myImport()
{
    var targetFile = File.openDialog ("Import your file", "*.jpg", multiSelect = false);

    function processFile(theFile)
    {
        try {

            var importOptions = new ImportOptions(theFile);
            importSafeWithError(importOptions);
        } catch (error) {

        }
    }

    function processFolder(theFolder)
    {   
        var files = theFolder.getFiles();
        var sequenceStartFile = testForSequence(files);
    }
    processFolder(targetFile);
    }
    myImport();
}
```

I am expecting to import an image not only to the project library, but also it needs to be added into bg comp to change bg.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the source of an existing file and this will effect all comps that use that file. Source files in the project window are `footageItem` objects and they have an attribute called `mainSource` which is a `file` object. So simply change the `mainSource` attribute of the bg footage. [More in the docs here](http://docs.aenhancers.com/items/footageitem/#footageitem-mainsource).

Answer (score 0):

Here in this script, after click on 'Import File' button, I got required result.

```
var selComp;
for (var i = 1; i <= app.project.numItems; i ++) 
{
if ((app.project.item(i) instanceof CompItem) && (app.project.item(i).name === 'MOVIE IMAGE')) {    
        selComp = app.project.item(i);
}
}
selComp.openInViewer(); // View Your Comp opened in after  effects
{
var w = new Window ("dialog");
var importFile = w.add ("button", undefined, "Import File");
importFile.onClick = ImportFile ;
importFromFolder.onClick = ImportFilesFromFolder ;
function ImportFile () {
app.beginUndoGroup("Import File");
var targetFile = File.openDialog("Import File");
        if (targetFile) {
        var importOptions = new ImportOptions (targetFile);                                                                
         var newLayer = app.project.importFile (importOptions);
         var insertLayer = selComp.layers.add(newLayer);
}
         $.writeln(newLayer.name);
app.endUndoGroup();
}   
w.show ();
}
```